# Не растягивать flex по высоте

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как отменить растягивание блока search-box?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body .top {
  background-color: #ededed;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}

body .top .row {
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}

body .top .navigation {
  color: #1a1919;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
}

body .top .navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

body .top .navigation ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

body .top .navigation ul a {
  padding-right: 30px;
  color: black;
}

body .top .navigation-active {
  color: #df3636;
}

body .top .page {
  color: #1a1919;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 24px;
}

body .search-box {
  flex-basis: auto;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: auto;
}

body .search-box button[type="submit"] {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.42px;
  background-color: #df3636;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

body .search-box button {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

body .search-box select {
  background-color: #313131;
  color: #999999;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: none;
}

body .search-box .disc {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

body .search-box .title {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

body .content {
  color: #1a1919;
  font-family: Oswald;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
}

body .content .col {
  padding: 0px;
}

body .content .sort {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

body .content select {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  color: #999999;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: none;
}

body .content .filter {
  border-radius: 13px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  color: #393939;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}

body .content .filter span {
  color: #df3636;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

body .content .price {
  background-color: #df3636;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

body .content .photo-car {
  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
}

body .content .photo-car img {
  width: 100%;
}

body .content .model {
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 26.4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

body .content .add {
  color: #1d1d1d;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 26.4px;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="section top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col page">Inventory</div>
        <!-- /.page -->
        <div class="col navigation">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inventory</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-active">Gird standard style 1</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.section -->
  <div class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 search-box">
          <div class="serch">
            <div class="title">Search inventory</div>
            <form action="#" method="post">
              <div class="disc">Condition</div>
              <select>
                  <option>new</option> 
                  </select>
              <div class="disc">Body</div>
              <select>
                  <option>Compact</option> 
                  </select>
              <div class="disc">Make</div>
              <select>
                  <option>BMW</option> 
                  </select>
              <div class="disc">Model</div>
              <select>
                  <option>x6</option> 
                  </select>
              <div class="disc">Max Mileage</div>
              <select>
                  <option>new</option> 
                  </select>
              <div class="disc">Year</div>
              <select>
                  <option>2016</option> 
                  </select>
              <div class="disc">Transmission</div>
              <select>
                  <option>Automatic</option> 
                  </select>
              <div class="disc">Color</div>
              <select>
                  <option>All color</option> 
                  </select>
              <button type="submit">SEARCH</button>
              <button type="reset">Reset all</button></p>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        </row>
        <div class="col-9 content">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col sort">
              SORT BY
              <select>
                    <option>Date: Newest first</option> 
                  </select>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col sort -->
          </div>
          <div class="row filtes">
            <div class="filter">Pricice <span>$2000 - $65.765</span>
              <a href="#"><img src="image/X.png"></a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.filter-one -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.row filter -->
          <!-- /.row -->
          <div class="row block-car">
            <div class="col-4 car">
              <div class="photo-car"><img src="image/kia.jpg" width="270px" height="150px"></div>
              <!-- /.photo-car -->
              <div class="price">$45.000</div>
              <!-- /.price -->
              <div class="model">BMW 535I, NAVI, LEATHER, ABS</div>
              <!-- /.model -->
              <div class="add">45/65 Automatic </div>
              <!-- /.add -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col car -->
            <div class="col-4 car">
              <div class="photo-car"><img src="image/kia.jpg" width="270px" height="150px"></div>
              <!-- /.photo-car -->
              <div class="price">$45.000</div>
              <!-- /.price -->
              <div class="model">BMW 535I, NAVI, LEATHER, ABS</div>
              <!-- /.model -->
              <div class="add">45/65 Automatic </div>
              <!-- /.add -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col car -->
            <div class="col-4 car">
              <div class="photo-car"><img src="image/kia.jpg" width="270px" height="150px"></div>
              <!-- /.photo-car -->
              <div class="price">$45.000</div>
              <!-- /.price -->
              <div class="model">BMW 535I, NAVI, LEATHER, ABS</div>
              <!-- /.model -->
              <div class="add">45/65 Automatic </div>
              <!-- /.add -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col car -->
            <div class="col-4 car">
              <div class="photo-car"><img src="image/kia.jpg" width="270px" height="150px"></div>
              <!-- /.photo-car -->
              <div class="price">$45.000</div>
              <!-- /.price -->
              <div class="model">BMW 535I, NAVI, LEATHER, ABS</div>
              <!-- /.model -->
              <div class="add">45/65 Automatic </div>
              <!-- /.add -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col car -->
            <div class="col-4 car">
              <div class="photo-car"><img src="image/kia.jpg" width="270px" height="150px"></div>
              <!-- /.photo-car -->
              <div class="price">$45.000</div>
              <!-- /.price -->
              <div class="model">BMW 535I, NAVI, LEATHER, ABS</div>
              <!-- /.model -->
              <div class="add">45/65 Automatic </div>
              <!-- /.add -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col car -->
            <div class="col-4 car">
              <div class="photo-car"><img src="image/kia.jpg" width="270px" height="150px"></div>
              <!-- /.photo-car -->
              <div class="price">$45.000</div>
              <!-- /.price -->
              <div class="model">BMW 535I, NAVI, LEATHER, ABS</div>
              <!-- /.model -->
              <div class="add">45/65 Automatic </div>
              <!-- /.add -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col car -->
            <div class="col-4 car">
              <div class="photo-car"><img src="image/kia.jpg" width="270px" height="150px"></div>
              <!-- /.photo-car -->
              <div class="price">$45.000</div>
              <!-- /.price -->
              <div class="model">BMW 535I, NAVI, LEATHER, ABS</div>
              <!-- /.model -->
              <div class="add">45/65 Automatic </div>
              <!-- /.add -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col car -->
            <div class="col-4 car">
              <div class="photo-car"><img src="image/kia.jpg" width="270px" height="150px"></div>
              <!-- /.photo-car -->
              <div class="price">$45.000</div>
              <!-- /.price -->
              <div class="model">BMW 535I, NAVI, LEATHER, ABS</div>
              <!-- /.model -->
              <div class="add">45/65 Automatic </div>
              <!-- /.add -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col car -->
            <div class="col-4 car">
              <div class="photo-car"><img src="image/kia.jpg" width="270px" height="150px"></div>
              <!-- /.photo-car -->
              <div class="price">$45.000</div>
              <!-- /.price -->
              <div class="model">BMW 535I, NAVI, LEATHER, ABS</div>
              <!-- /.model -->
              <div class="add">45/65 Automatic </div>
              <!-- /.add -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col car -->
            <div class="col-4 car">
              <div class="photo-car"><img src="image/kia.jpg" width="270px" height="150px"></div>
              <!-- /.photo-car -->
              <div class="price">$45.000</div>
              <!-- /.price -->
              <div class="model">BMW 535I, NAVI, LEATHER, ABS</div>
              <!-- /.model -->
              <div class="add">45/65 Automatic </div>
              <!-- /.add -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col car -->
            <div class="col-4 car">
              <div class="photo-car"><img src="image/kia.jpg" width="270px" height="150px"></div>
              <!-- /.photo-car -->
              <div class="price">$45.000</div>
              <!-- /.price -->
              <div class="model">BMW 535I, NAVI, LEATHER, ABS</div>
              <!-- /.model -->
              <div class="add">45/65 Automatic </div>
              <!-- /.add -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col car -->
            <div class="col-4 car">
              <div class="photo-car"><img src="image/kia.jpg" width="270px" height="150px"></div>
              <!-- /.photo-car -->
              <div class="price">$45.000</div>
              <!-- /.price -->
              <div class="model">BMW 535I, NAVI, LEATHER, ABS</div>
              <!-- /.model -->
              <div class="add">45/65 Automatic </div>
              <!-- /.add -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col car -->
            <div class="col-4 car">
              <div class="photo-car"><img src="image/kia.jpg" width="270px" height="150px"></div>
              <!-- /.photo-car -->
              <div class="price">$45.000</div>
              <!-- /.price -->
              <div class="model">BMW 535I, NAVI, LEATHER, ABS</div>
              <!-- /.model -->
              <div class="add">45/65 Automatic </div>
              <!-- /.add -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col car -->
            <div class="col-4 car">
              <div class="photo-car"><img src="image/kia.jpg" width="270px" height="150px"></div>
              <!-- /.photo-car -->
              <div class="price">$45.000</div>
              <!-- /.price -->
              <div class="model">BMW 535I, NAVI, LEATHER, ABS</div>
              <!-- /.model -->
              <div class="add">45/65 Automatic </div>
              <!-- /.add -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col car -->
            <div class="col-4 car">
              <div class="photo-car"><img src="image/kia.jpg" width="270px" height="150px"></div>
              <!-- /.photo-car -->
              <div class="price">$45.000</div>
              <!-- /.price -->
              <div class="model">BMW 535I, NAVI, LEATHER, ABS</div>
              <!-- /.model -->
              <div class="add">45/65 Automatic </div>
              <!-- /.add -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col car -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.row block-car -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-9 -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.section -->







  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить

```
align-items: flex-start;
```

В родителя   `search-box`